# How to make pdf with bootstrap styled html content which is come from back end codigniter file

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jspdf

i want to make tax invoice which is come from ajax with codeigniter view file that made with bootstrap style html content string. now i want to make that hrml string to jspdf

```
public function make_sticker_sheet_process()
    {
        if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
            $workorder_id=$this->input->post('workorder_id');
            $tot_order=count($workorder_id);
            $result=true;
            // $result=$this->order_model->make_sticker_sheet_mdl($workorder_id);
            if($result){
                $label=array();
                foreach ($workorder_id as $key => $id) {
                    $label[]=$this->make_label($id);
                }

                $info['label']=$label;

                $sticker=$this->load->view('admin/pdf/sticker_sheet_view',$info,TRUE);

                // $sticker=$this->load->view('admin/sticker_sheet_view',$info,TRUE);

                $report=array('status'=>1,'message'=>'<big>'.$tot_order.'</big> order id have been fixed as Purchased Order','sticker'=>$sticker);
                echo json_encode($report);exit;
            }
            else{
                $report=array('status'=>0,'message'=>'Somthing wrong please try again');
                echo json_encode($report);exit;
            }
        }
        else{
            show_error('No direct script access allowed');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For generating PDF you can use jsPDF and DomPDF.

1. JsPDF is example is attached below and for more you can use this [link](https://scotch.io/@nagasaiaytha/generate-pdf-from-html-using-jquery-and-jspdf). You have to copy past below code in local .html file and then check.

```js
var doc = new jsPDF();

 var elements = {
     '#print': function (element, renderer) {
         return true;
     }
 };

 $('#cmd').click(function () {   
     doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
         'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': elements
     });
     doc.save('demo.pdf');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
    <h3>This text come in pdf</h3>
</div>
<div id="print"></div>
<button id="cmd">Generate PDF</button>
```

2. In DomPDF you can use Internal style sheet. And load bootstraps css as Internal style sheet in header.

Comment: Thank you.But i have already used that ,it doesn't works as my way.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. i used the bootstrap in view file. you may use bootstrap link on which which file will be downloaded.

Comment: i just used like:

Comment: var w=window.open();$(w.document.body).html(info.sheet); after that i can put ctrl+p and then save as pdf